# Installation Of RockMongo on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to no-sql databases so can neone of you please help me with the installation of rockmongo. I have actually done pretty much okay but kinda missed something in between. The following where the steps that I had followed for installation which eventually failed

1.Installed Mongodb on my desktop

2.installed PHP 5.4.25

3.Installed IIS 7 on my working desktop

4.installed PHP manager for IIS

5.Created new modules for handlers basically the cgimodule

6.Enabled the extensions for mongodb php driver, a dll file that i had copied to the ext folder location of actual php installation

7.Deployed the entire rockmongo folder under C:\inetpub\wwwroot

8.Tried to open the index.php page

The page doesnot open??
Can u guys please point me into some sort of right direction how I'm supposed to install this one on windows.

Comment: Did u think of any alternatives to RockMongo??

Comment: What exactly happens when you open the page? Have you looked into the IIS error logs? - Where did you download the MongoDB driver? And which of the DLLs did you enable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Alternative to RockMongo :   
         docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/

     mongodb-tools.com/
2. Sticking to your question... Try Extracting steps wrt IIS from here:
   https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/blob/master/README.txt
3. Alternatively use this : https://code.google.com/p/rock-php/downloads/detail?name=rockmongo-on-windows-v0.0.1.rar&can=4&q=